# How to make function work with the same classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have found a nice script. Everything works fine except 1 thing; when I try to insert second list - it does not work. 
When you want the second block to open, the first one proceeds.

I tried to add different classes, but unfortunately, it does not work for me.
Where am I wrong?

```js
function tamingselect()
{
 if(!document.getElementById && !document.createTextNode){return;}
 
// Classes for the link and the visible dropdown
 var ts_selectclass='turnintodropdown';  // class to identify selects
 var ts_listclass='turnintoselect';  // class to identify ULs
 var ts_boxclass='dropcontainer';   // parent element
 var ts_triggeron='activetrigger';   // class for the active trigger link
 var ts_triggeroff='trigger';   // class for the inactive trigger link
 var ts_dropdownclosed='dropdownhidden'; // closed dropdown
 var ts_dropdownopen='dropdownvisible'; // open dropdown
/*
 Turn all selects into DOM dropdowns
*/
 var count=0;
 var toreplace=new Array();
 var sels=document.getElementsByTagName('select');
 for(var i=0;i<sels.length;i++){
  if (ts_check(sels[i],ts_selectclass))
  {
   var hiddenfield=document.createElement('input');
   hiddenfield.name=sels[i].name;
   hiddenfield.type='hidden';
   hiddenfield.id=sels[i].id;
   hiddenfield.value=sels[i].options[0].value;
   sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(hiddenfield,sels[i])
   var trigger=document.createElement('a');
   ts_addclass(trigger,ts_triggeroff);
   trigger.href='#';
   trigger.onclick=function(){
    ts_swapclass(this,ts_triggeroff,ts_triggeron)
    ts_swapclass(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],ts_dropdownclosed,ts_dropdownopen);
    return false;
   }
   trigger.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sels[i].options[0].text));
   sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(trigger,sels[i]);
   var replaceUL=document.createElement('ul');
   for(var j=0;j<sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option').length;j++)
   {
    var newli=document.createElement('li');
    var newa=document.createElement('a');
    newli.v=sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option')[j].value;
    newli.elm=hiddenfield;
    newli.istrigger=trigger;
    newa.href='#';
    newa.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
    sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option')[j].text));
    newli.onclick=function(){ 
     this.elm.value=this.v;
     ts_swapclass(this.istrigger,ts_triggeron,ts_triggeroff);
     ts_swapclass(this.parentNode,ts_dropdownopen,ts_dropdownclosed)
     this.istrigger.firstChild.nodeValue=this.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
     return false;
    }
    newli.appendChild(newa);
    replaceUL.appendChild(newli);
   }
   ts_addclass(replaceUL,ts_dropdownclosed);
   var div=document.createElement('div');
   div.appendChild(replaceUL);
   ts_addclass(div,ts_boxclass);
   sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(div,sels[i])
   toreplace[count]=sels[i];
   count++;
  }
 }
 
/*
 Turn all ULs with the class defined above into dropdown navigations
*/ 

 var uls=document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
 for(var i=0;i<uls.length;i++)
 {
  if(ts_check(uls[i],ts_listclass))
  {
   var newform=document.createElement('form');
   var newselect=document.createElement('select');
   for(j=0;j<uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a').length;j++)
   {
    var newopt=document.createElement('option');
    newopt.value=uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[j].href; 
    newopt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[j].innerHTML)); 
    newselect.appendChild(newopt);
   }
   newselect.onchange=function()
   {
    window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
   }
   newform.appendChild(newselect);
   uls[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newform,uls[i]);
   toreplace[count]=uls[i];
   count++;
  }
 }
 for(i=0;i<count;i++){
  toreplace[i].parentNode.removeChild(toreplace[i]);
 }
 function ts_check(o,c)
 {
   return new RegExp('\\b'+c+'\\b').test(o.className);
 }
 function ts_swapclass(o,c1,c2)
 {
  var cn=o.className
  o.className=!ts_check(o,c1)?cn.replace(c2,c1):cn.replace(c1,c2);
 }
 function ts_addclass(o,c)
 {
  if(!ts_check(o,c)){o.className+=o.className==''?c:' '+c;}
 }
}

window.onload=function()
{
 tamingselect();
 // add more functions if necessary
}
```

```css
.dropcontainer {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
}
.trigger {
    color: #777;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
    background: #fff url('../img/select-arrow-open.gif') right center no-repeat;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.trigger:hover {
    color: #777;
    background: #f5f5f5 url(../img/select-arrow-open.gif) right center no-repeat;
}
.activetrigger {
    color: #777;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
    background: #f5f5f5 url(../img/select-arrow-close.gif) right center no-repeat;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.activetrigger:hover {
    background: #f5f5f5 url(../img/select-arrow-close.gif) right center no-repeat;
    color: #777;
}
.activetrigger:active {
    background: #f5f5f5 url(../img/select-arrow-close.gif) right center no-repeat;
    color: #777;
}
.dropcontainer ul {
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    background: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px;
    top: 40px;
    right: 15px;
    width: 90%;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dropcontainer ul li {
    padding: 5px;
}
.dropcontainer ul li:hover {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    outline: none;
}
.dropcontainer ul li:first-child {
    display: none;
}
.dropcontainer ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
.dropdownhidden {
    display: none;
}
.dropdownvisible {
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
            <select class="turnintodropdown" id="1" name="1">
                <option>11111111111111</option>
                <option>11111111111111</option>
                <option>11111111111111</option>
                <option>11111111111111</option>
                <option>11111111111111</option>
            </select>  
            <select class="turnintodropdown" id="2" name="2">
                <option>22222222222222</option>
                <option>22222222222222</option>
                <option>22222222222222</option>
                <option>22222222222222</option>
                <option>22222222222222</option>
            </select> 
         </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming the second class to something like:
`<select class="turnintodropdown2" id="2" name="2">`
With this in the script
`var ts_selectclass='turnintodropdown2';`?

Comment: But I need both of them work, what should I do then to the first one? I`ve tried to do so, but the first one is then bringing some issues

Comment: I just ran it in a fiddle as it, seems to be functioning as intended: http://jsfiddle.net/psyonix/qm9222o4/

Comment: looks strange, it doesn`t work with my styles though

Comment: Please see my answer below, and let me know if that works. :)

Comment: I just saw you added the CSS, but there isn't anything in there that styles your form elements. Is that the whole sheet?

Comment: No, that is just the code that used for styling the list

Comment: Got it, well, at this point you're now asking 2 questions. We need to see the entire markup in order to provide useful advice. Also, if my answer fixed your initial issue for you, please select it as the answer. :)

Comment: If jQuery is available, as it appears from your tag, then why aren't you using it? If not, then remove the [jQuery] tag.

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/psyonix/g8n2vojw/1/

The markup:

```
<form action="#">
            <select class="turnintodropdown" id="1" name="1">
                <option>11111111111111</option>
                <option>11111111111111</option>
                <option>11111111111111</option>
                <option>11111111111111</option>
                <option>11111111111111</option>
            </select>  
            <select class="turnintodropdown2" id="2" name="2">
                <option>22222222222222</option>
                <option>22222222222222</option>
                <option>22222222222222</option>
                <option>22222222222222</option>
                <option>22222222222222</option>
            </select> 
         </form>
```

The script:

```
function tamingselect()
{
    if(!document.getElementById && !document.createTextNode){return;}

// Classes for the link and the visible dropdown
    var ts_selectclass='turnintodropdown2';
    var ts_selectclass='turnintodropdown';  // class to identify selects
    var ts_listclass='turnintoselect';      // class to identify ULs
    var ts_boxclass='dropcontainer';        // parent element
    var ts_triggeron='activetrigger';       // class for the active trigger link
    var ts_triggeroff='trigger';            // class for the inactive trigger link
    var ts_dropdownclosed='dropdownhidden'; // closed dropdown
    var ts_dropdownopen='dropdownvisible';  // open dropdown
/*
    Turn all selects into DOM dropdowns
*/
    var count=0;
    var toreplace=new Array();
    var sels=document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for(var i=0;i<sels.length;i++){
        if (ts_check(sels[i],ts_selectclass))
        {
            var hiddenfield=document.createElement('input');
            hiddenfield.name=sels[i].name;
            hiddenfield.type='hidden';
            hiddenfield.id=sels[i].id;
            hiddenfield.value=sels[i].options[0].value;
            sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(hiddenfield,sels[i])
            var trigger=document.createElement('a');
            ts_addclass(trigger,ts_triggeroff);
            trigger.href='#';
            trigger.onclick=function(){
                ts_swapclass(this,ts_triggeroff,ts_triggeron)
                ts_swapclass(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],ts_dropdownclosed,ts_dropdownopen);
                return false;
            }
            trigger.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sels[i].options[0].text));
            sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(trigger,sels[i]);
            var replaceUL=document.createElement('ul');
            for(var j=0;j<sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option').length;j++)
            {
                var newli=document.createElement('li');
                var newa=document.createElement('a');
                newli.v=sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option')[j].value;
                newli.elm=hiddenfield;
                newli.istrigger=trigger;
                newa.href='#';
                newa.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option')[j].text));
                newli.onclick=function(){
                    this.elm.value=this.v;
                    ts_swapclass(this.istrigger,ts_triggeron,ts_triggeroff);
                    ts_swapclass(this.parentNode,ts_dropdownopen,ts_dropdownclosed)
                    this.istrigger.firstChild.nodeValue=this.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
                    return false;
                }
                newli.appendChild(newa);
                replaceUL.appendChild(newli);
            }
            ts_addclass(replaceUL,ts_dropdownclosed);
            var div=document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(replaceUL);
            ts_addclass(div,ts_boxclass);
            sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(div,sels[i])
            toreplace[count]=sels[i];
            count++;
        }
    }

/*
    Turn all ULs with the class defined above into dropdown navigations
*/

    var uls=document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
    for(var i=0;i<uls.length;i++)
    {
        if(ts_check(uls[i],ts_listclass))
        {
            var newform=document.createElement('form');
            var newselect=document.createElement('select');
            for(j=0;j<uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a').length;j++)
            {
                var newopt=document.createElement('option');
                newopt.value=uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[j].href;
                newopt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[j].innerHTML));
                newselect.appendChild(newopt);
            }
            newselect.onchange=function()
            {
                window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
            }
            newform.appendChild(newselect);
            uls[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newform,uls[i]);
            toreplace[count]=uls[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        toreplace[i].parentNode.removeChild(toreplace[i]);
    }
    function ts_check(o,c)
    {
        return new RegExp('\\b'+c+'\\b').test(o.className);
    }
    function ts_swapclass(o,c1,c2)
    {
        var cn=o.className
        o.className=!ts_check(o,c1)?cn.replace(c2,c1):cn.replace(c1,c2);
    }
    function ts_addclass(o,c)
    {
        if(!ts_check(o,c)){o.className+=o.className==''?c:' '+c;}
    }
}

window.onload=function()
{
    tamingselect();
    // add more functions if necessary
}
```

Comment: Yeap, it really works, but the second one don`t want to get styles, and looks like default one

Comment: Are you referring to the CSS your form uses? If so, care to post it?